# Javascript plugin for editing (and saving) an XML file?

Tags: javascript, xml, plugins, wysiwyg, client-side

Is it possible to use a JavaScript plugin to open and save an XML file from the same server and directory it's running in?  I do not have any experience with JavaScript, and am rather ignorant as to its capabilities.

I am attempting to provide users with the ability to edit an XML-based configuration file via their browser.  Browser-based editors such as CodeMirror and ACE seem ideal for this, but can they read in XML from a file and then save it back?

Server-side code is not going to be possible in this case.  This simple plugin, if it is completed, will be uploaded to a SharePoint 2003 server and included in a web page (with a restrictive CMS) via an IFrame.

I have seen a JQuery plugin that a coworker added to a page via this method (hosted on SharePoint, linked with n iFrame), so JQuery may be a possibility as well.

If schema validation were possible in a web-based editor as well, that would also be useful.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Edit:  Anyone who would have access to this page would also have access to the SharePoint server that it (and the XML file which they want to edit) is hosted on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AlfonsoML [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161049/586621), you can't do this on the client side and will have to do it on the server side.

You can use JQuery to make Ajax calls to get the XML from the server as this post has shown [here](http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/). You will have to use Ajax again if you wanted to ship the XML contents back to the server to save it.

Comment: If you need a little more clarification let me know, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

No. Client-side code can't write on the server.

You need a server script to do that (just imagine the security nightmare if anyone was able to freely write to the server)

Comment: Well, there's technically already a serveer script, right?  SharePoint allows users to upload and download documents through their browser.  I can't modify that existing script, but is there a way to leverage it to get at the data?